Can't open wallet oracle apex
ORA-28353: Wallet Opening Failure and ORA-28759 Error with APEX OAuth2 Configuration
Hello everyone,
I'm currently facing an issue with Oracle 21c Express Edition involving wallet management and OAuth2 authentication in Oracle APEX. I would appreciate any guidance or insights you could provide.
Background:

Environment:

Oracle Database 21c Express Edition (21.3.0.0.0) running on Windows Server.
Oracle APEX 23.2.0 configured to use OAuth2 with Azure AD for authentication.
Wallet created with Oracle Wallet Manager and orapki.


Wallet Setup:

Initially, the wallet was created using orapki with auto-login enabled.
Certificates (DigiCert Global Root) were added successfully to the wallet.
The wallet is configured in the sqlnet.ora and tnsnames.ora files:
WALLET_LOCATION =
  (SOURCE =
    (METHOD = FILE)
    (METHOD_DATA =
      (DIRECTORY = D:\applis\oracle\db21c\wallet)
    )
  )

SSL_WALLET = D:\applis\oracle\db21c\wallet




Current Issues:

When attempting to open the wallet via SQL*Plus using:
ADMINISTER KEY MANAGEMENT SET KEYSTORE OPEN IDENTIFIED BY "<password>";

I consistently encounter the error:
ORA-28353: Failed to open the wallet


The wallet is accessible and can be opened successfully using Oracle Wallet Manager and orapki.


APEX Configuration:

OAuth2 is configured in APEX to authenticate using Azure AD with the following settings:

Authorization Endpoint URL: https://login.microsoftonline.com/.../oauth2/v2.0/authorize
Token Endpoint URL: https://login.microsoftonline.com/.../oauth2/v2.0/token


The error encountered in APEX is:
ORA-28759: Failed to open file

This error occurs when APEX tries to fetch the OAuth2 configuration from Azure AD.


Debugging Steps Taken:

Permission Check: Ensured that the OracleServiceXE has full control over the wallet directory and files.
Wallet Display: Verified with orapki that the wallet contents are correct and include the necessary certificates.
Parameter Validation: Confirmed that the wallet paths (wallet_root, ssl_wallet) are set correctly in Oracle parameters.
Log Files: Checked Oracle trace files which indicate the same ORA-28353 error when attempting to open the wallet.



Additional Details:

I've also attempted to relocate the wallet to D:\applis\wallet and updated all configuration files accordingly, but the issue persists.
The database was restarted, and the wallet was recreated multiple times with no success in resolving the issue via SQL*Plus, despite successful operations with Oracle Wallet Manager.

Request:
Given the persistent ORA-28353 and ORA-28759 errors, I'm looking for advice on:

Potential root causes of why the wallet won't open through SQL*Plus but works with Oracle Wallet Manager.
Any additional configurations or steps that might be needed for APEX to properly utilize the wallet.
Insights into what might be causing these errors, considering that permissions and configurations seem correct.

Thank you in advance for your help!
I tried all i find in stackover
